# How can I convert nginx config to HAProxy config?

Tags: nginx, haproxy

Can you help me to convert nginx config to haproxy config?
I'm a little bit confused with **if** statements in this config. How should I convert in in the right way for haproxy?
And what about $maint_ip and $upstrm variables. Can I create the same?

```
geo $maint_ip
{
default         yes;
172.22.0.0/16   no;
172.23.0.0/16   no;
172.24.0.0/16   no;
172.25.0.0/16   no;
172.26.0.0/16   no;
}

map "$maint_ip:$maintenance" $upstrm
{
default "https://wildfly";
"yes:yes" "http://techworks";
}

server {
        listen 172.23.5.30:80;
        server_name pay.example.com;
        location ~ /.* {return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;}
        access_log off;
}

server {
        server_name pay.example.com;
        listen 172.23.5.30:443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/pay.example.com.access.log ffb;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/pay.example.com.error.log;

        location / {

                if ($uri = '/'){
                        rewrite ^/$ https://pay.example.com/acq-company-web break;
                }

                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                #websocket configuration
                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection         "Upgrade";
                #proxy_set_header        Authorization      "";
                proxy_read_timeout      86400;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 16000m;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
                client_max_body_size 0;

                #proxy_pass https://pay-example-wildfly;
                if (-f /etc/nginx/maintenance.file) {
                        set $maintenance "yes";
                        }
                proxy_pass $upstrm;
                }
}
```

I expect the service to work on haproxy similarly to nginx